# How can I allow a user to remove and edit information that they created using a form?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have created a web page that allows users to create an album by entering information into a form. The problem I am having is that I want to allow the user to remove and edit information of the albums that they have created but I'm not really sure how to go about this. If someone could help guide me in the right direction I would really appreciate it. I would only like to use HTML, JavaScript and JSON for this project.

I just want to emphasize that I don't expect code to be written for me but as I am still learning sometimes I need some guidance.

Here is my code:

```js
// Empty array to store all album objects created.
let albm = [];

function onLoad() {
 let div = document.getElementById("albumList");
 
 if (sessionStorage.getItem("hasCodeRunBefore") === null) {
  sessionStorage.setItem("albums", JSON.stringify(albm));
  sessionStorage.setItem("hasCodeRunBefore", true);
 }
 else {
  albm = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("albums"));

  albm.forEach(function(a) {
   let albumTitle = document.createElement("h4");
   albumTitle.innerHTML = "<b>" + a.album + "</b>";

   let albumArtist = document.createElement("h5");
   albumArtist.innerHTML = a.artist;

   let lineBreak = document.createElement("br");

   let albumDetails = document.createElement("p");
   albumDetails.innerHTML = "<b>" + "Genre: " + "</b>" + 
          a.genre +
          "<br>" +
             "<b>" + "Release Date: " + "</b>" + 
             a.releaseDate +
             "<br>" +
             "<b>" + "Producer: " + "</b>" +
             a.producer +
             "<br>" +
             "<b>" + "Studio: " + "</b>" +
             a.studio;

   let songTitle = document.createElement("h6");
   songTitle.innerHTML = "<b>" + "Songs:" + "</b>";

   let songList = document.createElement("p");
   songList.innerHTML = a.songs;

   let editBtn = document.createElement("button");
   editBtn.innerHTML = "EDIT ALBUM";
   editBtn.classList.add("btn");

   editBtn.addEventListener("click", function onOpen() {
    document.getElementById("modal").showModal();
   });

   let deleteBtn = document.createElement("button");
   deleteBtn.innerHTML = "DELETE";
   deleteBtn.classList.add("btn", "ml-5", "del-btn");

   let horizontalRule = document.createElement("hr");
   
   div.appendChild(albumTitle);
   div.appendChild(albumArtist);
   div.appendChild(albumDetails);
   div.appendChild(lineBreak);
   div.appendChild(songTitle);
   div.appendChild(songList);
   div.appendChild(editBtn);
   div.appendChild(deleteBtn);
   div.appendChild(horizontalRule);
   div.appendChild(lineBreak);
  }); // forEach end.
 } // If, else end.
} // onLoad() end.

function Album(artist, album, genre, releaseDate, producer, studio, songs) {
 this.artist = artist;
 this.album = album;
 this.genre = genre;
 this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
 this.producer = producer;
 this.studio = studio;
 this.songs = songs;
} // Album() end.

function addAlbum() {
 albm = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("albums"));

 let newAlbum = new Album(
  document.getElementById("artistInput").value,
  document.getElementById("albumInput").value,
  document.getElementById("genreInput").value,
  document.getElementById("releaseDateInput").value,
  document.getElementById("producerInput").value,
  document.getElementById("studioInput").value,
  document.getElementById("songInput").value,
  );
 albm.push(newAlbum);
 sessionStorage.setItem("albums", JSON.stringify(albm));
} //addAlbum() end.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Music Share | User</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style-sheet.css">
</head>

<body onload="onLoad()">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col main-heading-border">
                <!-- Form heading -->
                <h1>Create Album:</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2"></div>
            <div class="col main-heading-border">
                <!-- Created albums heading. -->
                <h1>My Albums:</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col mt-4 container form-container">
                <!-- User input form start. -->
                <form class="mt-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="artistInput">Artist:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="artistInput" placeholder="Artist Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="albumInput">Album:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="albumInput" placeholder="Album Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="genreInput">Genre:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="genreInput" placeholder="Genre">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="releaseDateInput">Release Date:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="releaseDateInput" placeholder="Release Date">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="producerInput">Producer:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="producerInput" placeholder="Producer">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="studioInput">Studio:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="studioInput" placeholder="Studio">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="songInput">Songs:</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="songInput" rows="15"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Submit button. -->
                    <button onclick="addAlbum()" type="submit" class="btn float-right">CREATE ALBUM</button>
                </form>
                <!-- End -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-2"></div>
            <div class="col mt-4 container">
                <!-- Created albums start. -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col mt-3 album-list" id="albumList">
                       <dialog id="modal">
                                        <form class="mt-2">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="updateArtist">Artist:</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="updateArtist" placeholder="Artist Name">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="updateAlbum">Album:</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="updateAlbum" placeholder="Album Name">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="updateGenre">Genre:</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="updateGenre" placeholder="Genre">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="updateReleaseDate">Release Date:</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="updateReleaseDate" placeholder="Release Date">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="updateProducer">Producer:</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="updateProducer" placeholder="Producer">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="updateStudio">Studio:</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="updateStudio" placeholder="Studio">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="updateSongs">Songs:</label>
                                                <textarea class="form-control" id="updateSongs" rows="15"></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                            <button onclick="updateAlbum()" type="submit" class="btn">SAVE CHANGES</button>
                                        </form>
                                    </dialog>
                        </div> 
                        <!-- Modal end. -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you are using session storage instead of database, that's not wrong you only need to declare IDs for every parentElement. I mean, when you create a new album you do it in the same parent or div called "albumList". I recommend you to create new divs and make it your child container in order to identify that container later. If you permit me, here's your code using identifiers in the new containers. In this example I'm using "artist" as identifier.

I only modified your JS code:

```
<script>
    // Empty array to store all album objects created.
    let albm = [];

    function onLoad() {

        if (sessionStorage.getItem("hasCodeRunBefore") === null) {
            sessionStorage.setItem("albums", JSON.stringify(albm));
            sessionStorage.setItem("hasCodeRunBefore", true);
        }
        else {
            albm = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("albums"));

            albm.forEach(function(a) {
                addHTMLAlbum(a); // delegate the adding to another function
            });
        }
    }

    function Album(artist, album, genre, releaseDate, producer, studio, songs) {
        this.artist = artist;
        this.album = album;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
        this.producer = producer;
        this.studio = studio;
        this.songs = songs;
    }

    function addHTMLAlbum(a) {
      let div = document.getElementById("albumList"); // root for albums

      let singleAlbum = document.createElement("div"); // parent div
      singleAlbum.setAttribute("id", a.artist); // Set an ID for your album, let's say the artist is the ID

      let albumTitle = document.createElement("h4");
      albumTitle.innerHTML = "<b>" + a.album + "</b>";

      let albumArtist = document.createElement("h5");
      albumArtist.innerHTML = a.artist;

      let lineBreak = document.createElement("br");

      let albumDetails = document.createElement("p");
      albumDetails.innerHTML = "<b>" + "Genre: " + "</b>" + 
        a.genre +
        "<br>" +
        "<b>" + "Release Date: " + "</b>" + 
        a.releaseDate +
        "<br>" +
        "<b>" + "Producer: " + "</b>" +
        a.producer +
        "<br>" +
        "<b>" + "Studio: " + "</b>" +
        a.studio;

      let songTitle = document.createElement("h6");
      songTitle.innerHTML = "<b>" + "Songs:" + "</b>";

      let songList = document.createElement("p");
      songList.innerHTML = a.songs;

      let editBtn = document.createElement("button");
      editBtn.innerHTML = "EDIT ALBUM";
      editBtn.classList.add("btn");
      editBtn.onclick = updateAlbum;

      editBtn.addEventListener("click", function onOpen() {
        document.getElementById("modal").showModal();
      });

      let deleteBtn = document.createElement("button");
      deleteBtn.innerHTML = "DELETE";
      deleteBtn.classList.add("btn", "ml-5", "del-btn");
      deleteBtn.onclick = deleteAlbum;

      let horizontalRule = document.createElement("hr");

      // Append childs to the new container
      singleAlbum.appendChild(albumTitle);
      singleAlbum.appendChild(albumArtist);
      singleAlbum.appendChild(albumDetails);
      singleAlbum.appendChild(lineBreak);
      singleAlbum.appendChild(songTitle);
      singleAlbum.appendChild(songList);
      singleAlbum.appendChild(editBtn);
      singleAlbum.appendChild(deleteBtn);
      singleAlbum.appendChild(horizontalRule);
      singleAlbum.appendChild(lineBreak);
      div.appendChild(singleAlbum); // append container to albumList
    }

    function addNewAlbum() {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent refresh page
        albm = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("albums"));
        albm = albm ? albm : [];

        let newAlbum = new Album(
            document.getElementById("artistInput").value,
            document.getElementById("albumInput").value,
            document.getElementById("genreInput").value,
            document.getElementById("releaseDateInput").value,
            document.getElementById("producerInput").value,
            document.getElementById("studioInput").value,
            document.getElementById("songInput").value
        );
        albm.push(newAlbum);
        sessionStorage.setItem("albums", JSON.stringify(albm));

        addHTMLAlbum(newAlbum); // add new HTML Element without refresh
    } 

    function deleteAlbum() {
        event.preventDefault();
        albm = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("albums"));
        albm = albm.filter(({artist}) => artist !== this.parentElement.id); // filtered to remove the album using id
        this.parentElement.remove(); // This album is inside a div parent mentioned before
        sessionStorage.setItem("albums", JSON.stringify(albm)); // update session storage
    }

    function updateAlbum() {
        event.preventDefault();
        albm = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("albums"));

        // iterate all albums and update by id
        albm = albm.map((albumItem) => {
            if(this.parentElement.id === albumItem.artist) {
                let newAlbum = new Album(
                  document.getElementById("artistInput").value,
                  document.getElementById("albumInput").value,
                  document.getElementById("genreInput").value,
                  document.getElementById("releaseDateInput").value,
                  document.getElementById("producerInput").value,
                  document.getElementById("studioInput").value,
                  document.getElementById("songInput").value
                );
                let div = document.getElementById("albumList"); // root for albums

                let albumTitle = document.createElement("h4");
                albumTitle.innerHTML = "<b>" + newAlbum.album + "</b>";

                let albumArtist = document.createElement("h5");
                albumArtist.innerHTML = newAlbum.artist;

                let lineBreak = document.createElement("br");

                let albumDetails = document.createElement("p");
                albumDetails.innerHTML = "<b>" + "Genre: " + "</b>" + 
                  newAlbum.genre +
                  "<br>" +
                  "<b>" + "Release Date: " + "</b>" + 
                  newAlbum.releaseDate +
                  "<br>" +
                  "<b>" + "Producer: " + "</b>" +
                  newAlbum.producer +
                  "<br>" +
                  "<b>" + "Studio: " + "</b>" +
                  newAlbum.studio;

                let songTitle = document.createElement("h6");
                songTitle.innerHTML = "<b>" + "Songs:" + "</b>";

                let songList = document.createElement("p");
                songList.innerHTML = newAlbum.songs;

                let editBtn = document.createElement("button");
                editBtn.innerHTML = "EDIT ALBUM";
                editBtn.classList.add("btn");

                editBtn.addEventListener("click", function onOpen() {
                  document.getElementById("modal").showModal();
                });

                let deleteBtn = document.createElement("button");
                deleteBtn.innerHTML = "DELETE";
                deleteBtn.classList.add("btn", "ml-5", "del-btn");
                deleteBtn.onclick = deleteAlbum;

                let horizontalRule = document.createElement("hr");

                let parent = this.parentElement; // get the reference before button deletion, "this.elementParent" will not work because "this" won't exist once we do parent.innerHTML = "";
                parent.innerHTML = ""; // This album is inside a div parent mentioned before, so we update it
                parent.appendChild(albumTitle);
                parent.appendChild(albumArtist);
                parent.appendChild(albumDetails);
                parent.appendChild(lineBreak);
                parent.appendChild(songTitle);
                parent.appendChild(songList);
                parent.appendChild(editBtn);
                parent.appendChild(deleteBtn);
                parent.appendChild(horizontalRule);
                parent.appendChild(lineBreak);

                return newAlbum; // return updated values
            }

            return albumItem; // otherwise return old values
        });
        sessionStorage.setItem("albums", JSON.stringify(albm)); // update session storage
    } 

</script>
```

Comment: What does this line of code do?                                                                                                            albm = albm ? albm : [];

Comment: It's a ternary expression. If albm is not truthy (undefined, false, null, 0 or empty string) then albm is initialized with an empty array.

Comment: Aah, okay I understand. Thank you for replying. I was going through and testing the modified JavaScript code and I realized that in order to update the album I would have to type information into the create album form section and then click the edit album button in order to update the album to the new values. However, once I reload the page the values change back to the old data. Also, I intended for a modal to pop up when you click on the edit album button that would display another form where you can enter the new values you want to update and then for the album to be updated to the new

Comment: values once you click on the save changes button in the modal. Do you have any idea how to go about this? I tried changing the values of the newAlbum in updateAlbum() to the id's I gave in the modal form but that didn't work. I'm currently going through the code and trying to figure it out for myself but if you have any suggestions then I would really appreciate it, thank you.